# Where is the SQLite DB I've created using Phonegap app

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I am building my first Android app using Phonegap and the Phonegap app on my android tablet. It uses a SQLite DB. I want to be able to view some of the tables in the DB. I have rooted my tablet and installed several apps like SQLite Debugger, sqlite DB reader, file manager. None of them find the db. It is not listed under the Phonegap app or under the com.mydomain.app notation I set in the config.

Does anyone know where to find it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can see in eclipse  file explorer,  com.mydomain.app then database folder.
Note:If you not inserted data,you can not see

Comment: I don't have eclipse installed. I do have Android Studio but am not using it. I am using Dreamweaver and Phonegap server on pc and Phonegap app on tablet. I presume this is emulating the app on the tablet to see as it is being built. In File Explorer there is not an entry for com.mydomain.myapp and my db does not appear under com.adobe.phonegap.app

Comment: There is data in the tables by the way. I'm finding it very frustrating not being able to view what has been inserted when trying to find out why I am not getting what I expect when I do a select.

Answer (score 0):

I bought and installed SQLite Editor on to my tablet. It has a good search feature and found it. It was in:
/data/data/com.adobe.phonegap.app/app_database/http_192.168.1.117_3000/0000000000000001.db

The IP address is the local IP that phonegap server is running on.